# sen2cor L2A_Process not working, returns strange error

Tags: ubuntu, sentinel-2, sen2cor

I am trying to perform the correction on some sentinel 2 imagery using sen2cor L2A_Process on the 10 m resolution. Script returns some strange error. Below is the full output:

```
Sentinel-2 Level 2A Processor (Sen2Cor). Version: 2.8.0, created: 2019.02.20, supporting Level-1C product version 14.2 - 14.5 started ...
Old product version 14.2 detected, - will be updated to 14.5
Processing baseline will also be updated
Operation mode: TOOLBOX
Processing baseline: 99.99
Progress[%]:  0.00 : Generating datastrip metadata
Syntax error in metadata, see report file for details.
Schema file: S2-PDGS-TAS-DI-PSD-V14.2_Schema/S2_PDI_Level-1C_Datastrip_Metadata.xsd
Details: Element 'Image_Display_Order': This element is not expected. Expected is ( Spectral_Information_List ).
Incorrect datastrip L1C xml format
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/Sen2Cor-02.08.00-Linux64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sen2cor/L2A_Process.py", line 534, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/Sen2Cor-02.08.00-Linux64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sen2cor/L2A_Process.py", line 482, in main
    L2A_TILES = config.updateTiles()
  File "/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/Sen2Cor-02.08.00-Linux64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sen2cor/L2A_Config.py", line 3669, in updateTiles
    if self.create_L2A_Tile():
  File "/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/Sen2Cor-02.08.00-Linux64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sen2cor/L2A_Config.py", line 3694, in create_L2A_Tile
    self.getEntriesFromDatastrip()
  File "/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/Sen2Cor-02.08.00-Linux64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sen2cor/L2A_Config.py", line 3635, in getEntriesFromDatastrip
    self.spacecraftName = di.SPACECRAFT_NAME.text
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'SPACECRAFT_NAME'
```

I already found this answer to the same question: https://forum.step.esa.int/t/sen2cor-2-8-fails-on-product-from-early-2016-bool-object-has-no-attribute-spacecraft-name/16046 but none of the solutions works for me. 
Does anyone here knows what's this about?

UPDATE: With the S2A_OPER_PRD_MSIL1C_PDMC_20160413T104446_R063_V20160412T071340_20160412T071340.zip product the process actually began to perform correction however there are two new issues. The first is:

```
...
Progress[%]: 2.43 : PID-4188, L2A_Tables: band TCI exported, elapsed time[s]: 10.348, total: 1:16:13.163633
Syntax error in metadata, see report file for details.
Schema file: S2-PDGS-TAS-DI-PSD-V14.5_Schema/S2_User_Product_Level-2A_Metadata.xsd
Details: Element '{https://psd-13.sentinel2.eo.esa.int/PSD/User_Product_Level-2A.xsd}Level-2A_User_Product': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.
Progress[%]: 2.44 : PID-4188, L2A_ProcessTile: processing with resolution 10 m, elapsed time[s]: 10.025, total: 1:16:23.188470
...
```

the process is not interrupted at this point. Later another error occurs that terminates the script:

```
...
Progress[%]: 4.26 : PID-4188, L2A_Tables: stop export, elapsed time[s]: 0.157, total: 2:13:20.462217
Syntax error in metadata, see report file for details.
Schema file: S2-PDGS-TAS-DI-PSD-V14.5_Schema/S2_User_Product_Level-2A_Metadata.xsd
Details: Element '{https://psd-13.sentinel2.eo.esa.int/PSD/User_Product_Level-2A.xsd}Level-2A_User_Product': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.
Progress[%]: 100.00 : Application terminated successfully.
```

The suggested report.xml states the same as above.

Answer (score 0):

Could be an issue with the file system format on your harddrive.

I had the same problem (Ubuntu 16.04). I eventually discovered that the error dissapeared when I changed the output_dir to a different harddrive. The harddrive I was using for input and output was formatted with NTFS file system. When I reformated the harddrive to EXT4-format the error dissapeared, even when output_dir was on this harddrive.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here... This is ridiculous, I know, but I "solved" the problem formatting a pendrive as FAT32 filesystem (computer has NTFS), moved there the SAFE image and pointed to that location in sen2cor... It worked. I don't know why.